# Failing to install Quantstrat

Tags: r, quantstrat

I'm trying to install quantstrat package on Mac, but when I try

```
install.packages("quantstrat",repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```

I get this

```
package 'quantstrat' is available as a source package but not as a binary

Warning in install.packages :
  package 'quantstrat' is not available (as a binary package for R version 3.1.3)
```

When I download the tar.gz file from [here](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=316)
and try to install it from R:

```
install.packages("path/quantstrat",repos = NULL, type="source")
```

I get

```
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package 'path/quantstrat' had non-zero exit status
```

And when I try from Terminal

```
CMD INSTALL quantstrat_0.9.1669.tar.gz
```

I get

```
ERROR: dependencies ‘xts’, ‘TTR’, ‘blotter’, ‘FinancialInstrument’ are not available for package ‘quantstrat’
```

Comment: Do you have `xcode` installed?  You will need it to build from source on a Mac.  Also, you may need to use `install.packages(..., dependencies = TRUE`)`.

Comment: Then use `dependencies = TRUE` and see if it complains.

Comment: It still returns non-zero exit status. Should I apply over the .tar.gz file or over the folder unziped from the tar.gz file?

Comment: It's not clever, but I usually just go through and separately install any packages it wants and once they are all installed, go back and install the one I'm after.  You should be pointing to the *.tar.gz, R will unzip it automatically.

Comment: `install.packages("path/quantstrat",repos = NULL, type="source")` should be `install.packages("path/quantstrat_0.9.1669.tar.gz",repos = NULL, type="source")` but maybe that's what you were asking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt the tar.gz file is broken, you should try the zip file instead

So when I try

```
install.packages("C:/Program Files/Microsoft/MRO/R3.3.0/library/blotter_0.9.1741.zip",
                                   repos = NULL, type="source")

install.packages("C:/Program Files/Microsoft/MRO/R-3.3.0/library/quantstrat_0.9.1739.zip",
                                    repos = NULL, type="source")
```

then it works !